# Not able to access specific field of web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, configuration

I have below node in web.config file

```
<Properties>
  <Property Name="ConnectionString" Value="Data Source=testdb;User Id=scpan;password=testp@123;Persist Security Info=false"/>
</Properties>
```

I am trying to access the same using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` but not able to access the 'ConnectionString' tag. How to do it?

I am trying below code but its also not giving me the results

```
var section = (XmlElement)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Resource");
if (section.GetElementsByTagName("ConnectionString").Count > 0)
  {
    XmlElement element = (XmlElement)section.GetElementsByTagName("ConnectionString").Item(0);
    var fieldValue = element.Attributes["value"].Value;

   }
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: @mjwills I have updated my post

Answer (score 0):

You need to put connection string inside `connectionStrings` section inside `configuration` section in the `web.config` like this

```
<configuration>
    <!--other sections -->

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="connstring" connectionString="your--connection--string" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <!--other sections -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can I ask why ?

Comment: Its a old file and connectionstring has been added under the mentioned tab only

Comment: If it is an old file then how were you reading from it till now?

Comment: I tried with another using XML reader but not able to read..I have posted the code ..please have a look

Comment: Its a practice to put connection strings inside connectionStrings section inside the config file.